# String parsing with delimeter using Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse my string using double spaces.So i did wrote regex as `/  /g`.This does find all double spaces but i only need the ones such that between every consecutive doublespace there must be "=" sign.To make things clear let me explain with example:

For the input:

```
Hes id= 000014  Sbkd= 1151  Hesno= 0138075  Tur= 7  Dvkd= TL  name= james michael   king  id= 555  home=turkey
```

if i try with regex  `/  /g`  i get the matches as:

[image: Regex Output ScreenShot]

but as you see i dont need the double space after michael,obviously i don't want to split the name.

So is there any regex which will check the characters between matches and help solve my problem?

Note:I use Java ,but i just need the regex,lets assume i can't use any java functions.

Comment: This question is a little confusing. Why do you want to catch (2 spaces versus 3) and where does the `=` relate to the spaces, as they're completely separated by characters. Perhaps you're looking for `[space][space][characters]=`

Comment: What part of the text do you want to get or what is the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **lookahead** in your split regex:

```
/  (?=\w+=)/g
```

`(?=\w+=)` will make sure there is a `<name>=` after 2 spaces.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cJ6jF5/1)

In Java you have to use:

```
String[] arr = input.split("  (?=\\w+=)");
```

Comment: I agree. Rather than looking at where you need to find double spaces, look at what surrounds the double spaces 100% of the time and that'll help your regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to use lookaheads or lookbehinds, another way is to simply check after the double spaces for any phrase, followed by an `=` sign.

`/(  )[^= ]+=/` will give you the result you are looking for.